# How to access outside variables in an action event handler (javafx button)?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm a bit of a javafx noob. I want to make it so this button updates the "GraphView" object called "viewGraph", but I don't know how to properly do this because I can't access outside variables in the setOnAction event. I would also want to make startVertice and endVertice outside of the event class as well but I don't know how to do that.

I would think the answer would be to somehow pass the variables in using parameters but I don't know how to do that.

I tried looking stuff up and trying random syntax stuff but I still dont know what to do. It seems simple though.

```java
WeightedGraph<Campus> graph = new WeightedGraph<>(vertices, edges);

        Label startCampus = new Label("Starting Campus: ");
        Label endCampus = new Label("    Ending Campus: ");
        TextField startText = new TextField();
        TextField endText = new TextField();
        Button displayShortestPathBtn = new Button("Display Shortest Path");

        HBox input = new HBox();
        input.getChildren().addAll(startCampus, startText, endCampus, endText, displayShortestPathBtn);
        input.setPadding(new Insets(25, 0, 0, 0));

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        GraphView viewGraph = new GraphView(graph);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(viewGraph, input);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(50, 50, 25, 50));


        displayShortestPathBtn.setOnAction((event) -> {
            int startVertice = Integer.parseInt(startText.getText());
            int endVertice = Integer.parseInt(endText.getText());

            WeightedGraph<Campus>.ShortestPathTree shortestPathGraph = graph.getShortestPath(startVertice);
            ArrayList<Integer> path = (ArrayList)shortestPathGraph.getPath(endVertice);

            /*
            What I want to do:

            viewGraph = new GraphView(graph, path);
            */
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("Final Exam");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vbox));
        primaryStage.show();
```

I just want to be able to access the outside variables but idk if that's possible or if I'm approaching the problem correctly in the first place.

Comment: What do you expect the results to be? Replacing the existing `GraphView`? You could use `vbox.getChildren().set(0, new GraphView(graph, path));` for this purpose (That is unless the existing `GraphView` allows for modification, which would be preferable).

Comment: @fabian GraphView does have a function to update things but I can't access the variable inside the action even in the first place

Comment: You can access it. You just can reintialize it as it has to be final to use it in the handle.